# Why getting a larger image box when rotating?

Tags: alignment, includegraphics

I'm trying to put two images side by side, using a simple code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics{example-image}
\includegraphics{example-image}

\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

However, I may need  to rotate one them, when I try rotating one of them, e.g.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[]{five.png}
\includegraphics[angle=180]{five.png}
\caption{Caption text\label{fig:scaled_diss}}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

what I get is the second image positioned below the first one, which clearly I don't want.

[image]

How can I solve this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `\rotatebox` with the `origin=c` option to keep the rotation about the image center, rather than base.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=.3]{example-image}
\rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{\includegraphics[scale=.3]{example-image-a}}
\caption{Caption text\label{fig:scaled_diss}}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]